# degree five genus one curves without rational points?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth genus one curve over $k$. I don't call it elliptic curve because it will have no rational points.

By **index** of $X$ we mean the *smallest degree* of a closed point on $X$; equivalently by Riemann-Roch that's the same as the smallest positive degree of a divisor, or the greatest common divisor of all degrees of closed points.

Of course, the index of a curve equals one if the field is algebraically closed, so we consider non-closed fields here. For example, a smooth cubic curve in $\mathbb{P^2}$ can have index one or three.

**Here is the **question****: can one characterize fields $k$ which admit genus one curves of index $d$?

I am especially interested in the $d = 5$ case; then the model of such curve over algebraic closure is a linear section of the Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$. For which fields do we have genus one curves of index $5$? Is there a way to figure this out without writing explicit equations?

*UPDATE:* I actually don't fully understand the case of number fields. Are all number fields allowed?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of such fields?  Every function field of transcendence degree at least one over an uncountable algebraically closed field (every $d>1$ works).

Comment: I was hoping for a condition in terms of arithmetic of the field, e.g. existence of a finite field extension of a certain type.

Comment: This article is relevant to understanding the case $d=5$ : Tom Fisher, Minimisation and reduction of 5-coverings of elliptic curves
Algebra & Number Theory (2013) http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/ant.2013.7.1179

Comment: I think all number fields are allowed, see this article by William Stein: https://wstein.org/papers/index/

Comment: .. and finite fields will never have that property as all genus one curves over a finite field have a point.

Comment: I think it is way too naive to expect a complete classification of such fields. The arithmetic of general fields is quite complicated. There are some weird fields out there.

Comment: @DanielLoughran: my most naive guess after reading Ari Shnidman's reply is: it's necessary and sufficient to have a degree 5 extension L/k. Is this false? Is it at least necessary?

Comment: Well if there is curve of index $5$ then certainly there is a degree $5$ extension of $k$, given by the field over which a rational point is obtained. But the converse need not hold: over a finite field there is an extension of degree $5$, but every curve of genus $1$ has a rational point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll address the case $d = 5$ over any number field, without recourse to Gross-Zagier formulas and Tate-Shafarevich groups.  If $X$ has index 5, then it has order 5 in $H^1(k,E)$, hence comes from $H^1(k,E[5])$, where $E$ is the Jacobian. I assume the converse is not true (presumably some 5-torsion classes come from torsors of index 25), but I'll give examples of cohomology classes which are visibly of index 5.

Over *any* field there exists at least one elliptic curve with a rational point of order 5, or by duality, a subgroup (scheme) isomorphic to $\mu_5$. Over $\mathbb{Q}$ there is even an elliptic curve (of conductor 50 I believe) that contains both.  In the first case, consider the induced map
$$\mathrm{Hom}(G_k,\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}) = H^1(k,\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})  \stackrel{i}{\to} H^1(k, E[5])$$
In the dual case, consider  $H^1(k, \mu_5) \simeq k^{\times}/k^{\times 5}$. The kernel of $i$ comes from the $k$-rational points in the kernel of the dual isogeny, so it has $\mathbb{F}_5$-dimension at most 1, in either case.  The image of $i$ gives you torsors which have index 1 or 5 (since they are twists of a 5-isogeny).  The index is 1 precisely if the cohomology class "comes from rational points", i.e if its in the image of $E(k)/5E(k)$ under the coboundary map. If $k$ is a number field, then the latter is a finite group, whereas $H^1(k, \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$ or $H^1(k, \mu_5)$ are both infinite (see the explicit descriptions above). So there are infinitely many index 5 PHS $X$.