# Over which fields does every algebraic curve of genus one have a rational point?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Over which fields does every smooth projective geometrically connected curve of genus one have a rational point?

Comment: Algebraically closed and finite fields are examples. You ask for which $K$ is $H^1(K,E)=0$ for all elliptic curves $E/K$.

Comment: [Pseudo-algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_algebraically_closed_field) fields are also examples. But I don't think there's a specific term. One construction which might interest you is this: start from any field $k_0$, let $E$ be a genus $1$ curve and $k_1 = k_0(E)$ its function field: then $E$ has a point over $k_1$; repeat transfinitely, taking inductive limits at limit steps: you will eventually get a field with the property you asked, in which $k_0$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I don't understand your construction. Each time you make an extension don't get new non-isotrivial curves? Why would they have a rational point?

Comment: Yes, each extension brings new curves, which is why the process must be iterated transfinitely (repeat with these new curves, and so on): but you run out of curves before you run out of ordinals. See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303168 theorem 2.3 and lemma 2.4 for a related situation (where we add points to Severi-Brauer varieties rather than curves of genus 1).

Comment: (Disclaimer: I didn't check too carefully that the argument which works for Severi-Brauer varieties also works in your case, so don't take my word for it. This is why I'm writing this as a comment and not as an answer.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathoverflow! This holds for finite fields. For an infinite field a necessary condition could be that every element has roots of arbitrary degree, otherwise you can construct a nontrivial torsor. See here for a discussion and references: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377081/degree-five-genus-one-curves-without-rational-points and this paper for a sharp recent result: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crelle-2016-0037/html